# Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS with Apache RedirectPermanent for sites that use modperl

Tags: apache, redirect, https

I have an Apache 2.4 site that serves content that is generated by `modperl` via HTTPS. The relevant `Location` section is as follows:

```
<Location />
  SetHandler modperl
  PerlResponseHandler MyService
</Location>
```

I would now like to enable the same content via HTTP as well. The following `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myservice.conf` works to some extend in that it redirects URLs with trailing paths but not the "root" page (say, `http://myservice.mycompany.com`). I suspect this is (also) because this page is special in that it is backed by `modperl`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  LogLevel debug
  ServerName myservice.mycompany.com
  RedirectPermanent / https://myservice.mycompany.com
</VirtualHost>
```

So how can I use `RedirectPermanent` for redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS for an entire Apache sites, including those pages that are backed by `modperl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect any path in your site, you probably want to use `mod_rewrite`. These rules should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(I've removed the `perl` and `mod_perl` tags from this question. The rewrite happens long before the server cares about how it's going to serve the content.)

Comment: Excellent, that seems to work fine. I still don't see why the other method with `RedirectPermanent` (i.e. the one that uses `mod_alias` instead of `mod_rewrite`) did not work also, but this is only of academic interest now.

Comment: @rookie099: Your original version does work. But it only redirects the single path `/`. My version redirects all paths on the server. You could probably do something using [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead of `RedirectPermanent`.